# Angular 2 Tutorial, unhandled promise rejection on routing section

Tags: angular

I am attempting to follow the official tutorial. Everything went well until the Routing section [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html).  When I reach the section where we remake app.component.ts and change the app.module.ts, I get a loading screen on localhost, console error is:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'hero' since it isn't a known property of 'my-hero-detail'.

I ensured that it wasn't a mistake I may have made previously in the tutorial by copy pasting relevant files from [here](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-4/ts/plnkr.html).  The project works exactly as shown on the plunker.

My question is what is causing the promise to fail when it works in earlier versions, and where can I learn how to fix it?

Code excerpts:

From app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
selector: 'my-heroes',
template: `
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
`,
```

...

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
heroes: Hero[];
selectedHero: Hero;

constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

getHeroes() {
this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getHeroes();
}

onSelect(hero: Hero) { this.selectedHero = hero; }
}
```

From app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <my-heroes></my-heroes>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

from app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent }  from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }  from './hero.service';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    HeroService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

from hero-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="hero">
      <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
      <div>
        <label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>name: </label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
}
```

EDITED to fix plunkr link

Comment: They totally screw up.. Btw your plunker link is not working

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the same error following the tutorial. They might missed a little change in the `app.module.ts`. The `HeroDetailComponent` has not been imported and added to the declaration array. Hence the property `hero` of this component is unknown.

Adding the import as well as the respective declaration should fix this problem:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';

import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroesComponent,
        HeroDetailComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        HeroService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I assume they forgot to document that change. If you take a look into the next chapter (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) you will find this change in the `app.module.js` file.

Comment: Did not work for Nested router-outlet - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10805

Comment: Thank you!
I guess there need to be added a patch to this file on github:
https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/toh-5/ts/app/app.module.1.ts
I'm not aware of procedure of submiting patches. Somebody plz do it!

Answer (score 6):

If you read down a couple paragraphs(more like 30 paragraphs), you'll see

Delete the last line of the template with the `<my-hero-detail>` tags.

This will stop that error

I am going through the tutorial now and was actually searching for the answer haha

Comment: It still doesn't really clear it up. After making the changes, the app is supposed to have the same functionality as before.  The tutorial even makes a big deal of how the changes don't break anything, even though they do.

Comment: Yea I think they messed up a little there

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
In my case it helped copying the complete @Component-Part from the file "hero-detail.component.ts" into the file "app.component.ts". After restarting the application, it worked fine. It still worked, even as i undone my changes.

It seems to me, that something was in the cache - and by this action, the cache was cleared.

Comment: This actually helped fix the problem for me.  I just stopped the `npm start` command and ran it again and everything worked.  Make sure you save all of your files and everything is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For the edge case that I experienced, make sure to rebuild!!! the `watch` on `ng serve` does not watch directories, but instead watches files used in the initial build. It will not transpile new pages. Narrowly avoided jumping out the window here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and I've done the following changes to make it work again for part 5:

1. [Change the files as documented in Lukas Melzer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884167/angular-2-tutorial-unhandled-promise-rejection-on-routing-section/38899398#38899398)
2. Import HeroService and add HeroService as a provider in app.component.ts :

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

   @Component({
       selector: 'my-app',
       template: `
           <h1>{{title}}</h1>
           <my-heroes></my-heroes>
       `,
       providers: [ HeroService ]
   })

   export class AppComponent {
       title = 'Tour of Heroes';
   }
   ```

With theses changes I had no more errors. Also now the title appears twice as I would expect it (called from heroes.component and app.component). I removed the one in heroes.component.

Comment: These apparently belong in app.module.ts .

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message, but my mistake was use of a capital letter in a file name (capital C in `./hero-detail.Component` was the problem):
`import { HeroDetailComponent}`    from `'./hero-detail.Component'`;

Answer (score 0):

I found success doing this:

- Remove `<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>` from the heroes.component.ts template (currently still in the heroes.component.ts file)

Here is how the Heroes.component.ts file looks before and after:

Before:

```
... top file contents ...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-heroes',
    template: `
        <h2>My Heroes</h2>
        <ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
            <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>

        <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
        `,

... remaining file ...
```

After:

```
... top file contents ...

@Component({
    selector: 'my-heroes',
    template: `
        <h2>My Heroes</h2>
        <ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
            <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        `,

... remaining file ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always refer

> Run the [live example](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview) for this part.

My problem was fixed after editing `app.module.ts` as per in [live example](https://embed.plnkr.co/?show=preview)

I edited following part:

```
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent
  ],
```