# Angular Tutorial not working on Chapter 5(Routing)

Tags: angular

I am doing the Angular's Tutorial(Tutorial: Tour of Heroes), but got stuck and would like to have some help.

I was on Chapter5(ROUTING), and went on till I reached to "Refactor routes to a Routing Module".
At this point, I thought I could see my codes working on the browser by executing `npm start`, but the screen stopped on `Loading AppComponent content here ...`.

I have uploaded my tutorial codes to GitHub(https://github.com/btfurukawatkr/angular-tour-of-heroes).
Can anyone help me with what I have done wrong ?

Tutorial:https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: You are having an error in your console. Why don't you provide it in your question?

Comment: actually, I didn't notice any errors when I did the `npm start`, so that's what was confusing me

Comment: You should add error message from your browser console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the developer console `Can't bind to 'hero' since it isn't a known property of 'my-hero-detail'.` Error is in `<my-hero-detail [ERROR ->][hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>` because you haven't added `@Input` decorator to `hero` property in `HeroDetailComponent`. Also you haven't added `<base href="/">` into `index.html`.

**hero.detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
//...

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html'
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() private hero: Hero;
  //...
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->   
    <base href="/">
    <!-- ... -->  
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Read [Component Communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) tutorial.

Comment: `<base href="/">` did the fix. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

If you have errors in angular you should provide the error from the developer console.

Anyway you can find your solution here: [Angular 2 Tutorial, unhandled promise rejection on routing section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884167/angular-2-tutorial-unhandled-promise-rejection-on-routing-section)